# Can we use single spring kafka producer, consumer bean for different topics (same serializers)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am using spring boot *spring-kafka* library. So I need to send and consume data over kafka over multiple topics. So, lets say I have two features *feature1*, *feature2*, currently this is the producer and consumer config I have:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> featureProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

    return config;
}

// feature one producer bean

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<Long, FeatureOneObject> featureOneKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(featureProducerFactory()));
}

// feature two producer bean

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<Long, FeatureTwoObject> featureTwoKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(featureProducerFactory()));
}

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> featureConsumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);

    return props;
}

// feature one consumer bean config

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Long, FeatureOneObject> featureOneConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new LongDeserializer(),
            FeatureOneObject.class);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, FeatureOneObject> featureOneListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, FeatureOneObject> factory
            = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(featureOneConsumerFactory());

    return factory;
}

// feature two consumer bean config

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Long, FeatureTwoObject> featureTwoConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new LongDeserializer(),
            FeatureTwoObject.class);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, FeatureTwoObject> featureTwoListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, FeatureTwoObject> factory
            = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(featureTwoConsumerFactory());

    return factory;
}
```

This way I unnecessarily have to create same type of bean everytime. I was trying to reduce that effort..

Instead of having many beans get created like above, one producer and one consumer for EACH feature, I wanted to check if we can use a single bean for consumer and producer to send and consume data, given that it works for the same serializers. *(for key, LongSerializer, for value JsonSerializer)*

I was trying out something like below:

```
// Producer bean

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<Long, Object> producerKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(featureProducerFactory()));
}

// CONSUMER bean

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Long, Object> featureConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new LongDeserializer(),
            Object.class);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, Object> featureListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, Object> factory
            = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(featureConsumerFactory());

    return factory;
}
```

But getting following error from the same (error thrown uses different class name than what I mentioned in the example above, though its the same structure):

> Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming messageEndpoint handler details:Method [public void com.nsltxn.kafka.FilterRelatedCUDCDKafkaEventHandler.handleFilterRelatedCUDCDRequests(com.nsltxn.dto.FilterRelatedCUNotification)]Bean [com.nsltxn.kafka.FilterRelatedCUDCDKafkaEventHandler@5fee09f9]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to [com.nsltxn.dto.FilterRelatedCUNotification] for GenericMessage ......`

Can someone help me with this? Whether this way of doing is even possible, if yes then what mistake I might be doing... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is fine, but on the Consumer side, use a `JsonMessageConverter`  with a `ByteArrayDeserializer` instead of a `JsonDeserializer`.

That way, the converter can detect the type to convert to from the method signature.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion

You can continue to use the `JsonSerializer` on the producer side.

Comment: thanks @gary-russell, its working now.. 
But wanted to know if this is a good practice to follow? like to have single producer and consumer beans OR its better to use different producer, consumer beans for each topic/feature?

Comment: one thing is if for each feature I want to have a unique consumer group, that won't be possible if I only use a single consumer bean.

Comment: Generally better to use fewer beans. That is not correct, the group from the factory is only a default, you can override it by specifying a unique group on each listener. It is best practice to use different groups when the listeners are not related. It is good practice to give each `@KafkaListener` an id. By default that will be used as the group. See the Javadocs for the annotation. Several other factory properties can be overridden on it.